# how to access view controller functions in the app delegate in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, function, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

> Xcode gives me the error "Instance member 'pauseGame322' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if  appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    ViewController.pauseGame322(ViewController)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add observer in your view controller

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
selector: #selector(applicationWillTerminate),
name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification,
object: nil)
```

callback

```
@objc func applicationWillTerminate() {
    
     self.pauseGame322()
    
}
```

Comment: In swift 5.9 name of the notification changed to: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification